# AWS S3 public URL without Expiry date and Token

Tags: android, ios, flutter, amazon-s3

Is there any way that I can generate a Public URL without any expiry date and token? I am new in flutter and developing an application to upload the image into the AWS s3 but getting URL with token.

I'm using below code

```
    Future<String> upload(String image,String filePath) async {
    try {
      print('In upload');
      // Uploading the file with options

      File local = File(image);
      final key =  filePath + DateTime.now().toString();
      Map<String, String> metadata = <String, String>{};
      metadata['name'] = 'filename';
      metadata['desc'] = 'A test file';
      S3UploadFileOptions options = S3UploadFileOptions(
          accessLevel: StorageAccessLevel.guest, metadata: metadata);

      UploadFileResult result = await Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
          key: key,
          local: local,
          options: options,
          onProgress: (progress) {
            print("PROGRESS: " + progress.getFractionCompleted().toString());
          });

      setState(() {
        _uploadFileResult = result.key;
        print(_uploadFileResult);

      });
      return await getUrl().then((value){
        return value;
      });

    } catch (e) {
      print('UploadFile Err: ' + e.toString());

    }
    return '';
  }
```

for taking url

```
Future<String> getUrl() async {
    try {
      print('In getUrl');
      String key = _uploadFileResult;
      S3GetUrlOptions options = S3GetUrlOptions(
          accessLevel: StorageAccessLevel.guest, expires: 10000);
      GetUrlResult result =
      await Amplify.Storage.getUrl(key: key, options: options);

      setState(() {
        _getUrlResult = result.url;
        print(_getUrlResult);
      });

      return _getUrlResult;
    } catch (e) {
      print('GetUrl Err: ' + e.toString());
    }
    return '';
  }
```

Comment: did you find any solution? i am also facing this issue

Comment: use simple s3. https://pub.dev/packages/simple_s3

Comment: Where i get Pool ID? i am beginner